# Trying to simulate exp gain

Tags: javascript, html

I have this:

```
Strength: Lv <span id="Strengthlv">1</span> <span 
id="StrengthCexp">0</span> / <span id="StrengthMexp">100</span>
                    <br />
```

To show Strength: Lv 1 0/100

I'm trying to make a function ( later i want it tied to my cookie clicker where you get 1 exp for strength everytime you press the button) that everytime you press the button you get 1 exp. Then it keeps going up until its the same as the max exp.

I have tried what I did in a previous function ( what i did for my cookie clicker) but it did not turn out the same.

My JavaScript code:

```
var Strength = 1;
var Strengthlv = 1;
var StrengthCexp = 0;
var StrengthMexp = 100;
var Magic = 1;
var MagicCexp = 0;
var MagicMexp = 100;

function Strengthexp(){
    if (StrengthCexp != StrengthMexp){
        StrengthCexp = StrengthCexp + 1;
        document.getElementById("StrengthCexp").innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
    }else{
        Strengthlv = Strengthlv + 1
        StrengthCexp = 0
        Strength = Strength + 1
        document.getElementById('Strengthlv').innerHTML = Strengthlv;
        document.getElementById('StrengthCexp').innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
        document.getElementById('Strength').innerHTML = Strength;
    }
        var NextMaxStrengthExp = StrengthMexp * 1.5;
        document.getElementById('StrengthMexp').innerHTML = 
NextMaxStrengthExp;

}
```

HTML code to test if onclick gain exp works:

```
<button onclick="Strengthexp()">Click Me!</button>
                <br />
```

I expect the StrengthCexp to keep increaseing by 1 on click of the button until StrengthCexp = StrengthMexp . Then It will increase lv by 1 and Strength amount by 1 then reset StrengthCexp to zero then change the StrengthMexp to be more then the first amount. the actual output it isn't doing anything onclick so i feel like i got something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Strength = 1;
      var Strengthlv = 1;
      var StrengthCexp = 0;
      var StrengthMexp = 100;
      var Magic = 1;
      var MagicCexp = 0;
      var MagicMexp = 100;
      var NextMaxStrengthExp = StrengthMexp;

      function Strengthexp(){
        if (StrengthCexp <= NextMaxStrengthExp){
          StrengthCexp = StrengthCexp + 1;
          document.getElementById("StrengthCexp").innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
        }else{
          Strengthlv = Strengthlv + 1
          StrengthCexp = 0
          Strength = Strength + 1
          NextMaxStrengthExp = NextMaxStrengthExp * 1.5;
          document.getElementById('StrengthMexp').innerHTML = NextMaxStrengthExp;
          document.getElementById('Strengthlv').innerHTML = Strengthlv;
          document.getElementById('StrengthCexp').innerHTML = StrengthCexp;
          document.getElementById('Strength').innerHTML = Strength;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Also no element by id `Strength`

Comment: its still not adding one to strengthcexp when i press the button. im so confused. my code looks solid http://prntscr.com/nt3ddv

Comment: Ok for some reason it works in a diffrent online editor and not brackets. what do you think is wrong with my code. Can i post the whole thing? i put in the tiny function on codeio and it worked. Im not sure why it doesn't work in my normal program

Comment: Should I make several JavaScript files? I wanted most of these functions to work with these other variables tho dang. im new to JavaScript / html is it bad to have to much in one JavaScript.